# Store every username in the firebase database into an array variable?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to build a social media app and I have the design down and Ive been up all night trying to figure this out with no luck. I'm fairly new to coding so any help would be appreciated! Thank You! (Also my apologies if this question is already asked. Ive tried looking everywhere and couldn't find anything)

Comment: Please show us your code, along with any error messages.

Comment: you can set a map on the FirebaseDatabase and inside map you can put your array

Comment: There's no way to answer as we don't understand the question. You should ask a clear question, include your Firebase structure and a code snippet so we understand what you are trying to do. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to start off you need to create variable which will be database reference and array where the data will be stored such as:

```
var Array = [String]() //array of strings (usernames)
var ref : DatabaseReference! //define type of variable
```

then you assign it in viewDidLoad:

```
 ref = Database.database().reference()
```

using this you'll be able to access your database and load current users:

```
            ref.child("data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
                self.listIsEmpty()
                print("The user has no data in the database")
                return
            }
            let userItem = value["Username"] as? [String] //loads the data
            self.Array = userItem! //saves data to array
```

and then finally to write data you start by appending array which we have:

```
Array.append(textField.text) //reference textfield where username is or variable

ref.child("data").setValue(["Username":self.Array])
```